# How to access repeater field of a custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called `donation_group` it has a custom_field called `donate_pages` which is a repeater field. This `donate_pages` has again fields called `donation_object` and `amount_received`. 
I want to access these custom fields in my controller ie php file.

This is the code I have tried so far

```
 $donation_group_posts = Timber::get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'donation_group'
    ));

    foreach ( $donation_group_posts as $dg_post ) {
        $dg_donate_pages = $dg_post -> donate_pages;
        echo "dg_donate_pages", $dg_donate_pages;
    }
```

When I echo dg_donate_pages, I am only getting the number of rows that repeater field has. 
How can I get its values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $donation_group_posts as $dg_post ) {
    $dg_id = $dg_post->ID;

    if(have_rows('YOUR_REPEATER_SLUG', $dg_id)){
        while(have_rows('YOUR_REPEATER_SLUG', $dg_id)) : the_row();
            echo get_sub_field('YOUR_FIELD_SLUG');
        endwhile;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @samuel it worked.